# DIV as big as browser window with no javascript

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create a DIV as big as the browser window and then show the website using vertical scrolling. The effect I am looking for is similar to the one in [THIS PAGE](http://themeforest.net/item/x-the-ultimate-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/5871901) (note the big banner that is always as big as the browser window, and the content at the bottom):

With this HTML in mind:

```
<div class="banner">
   This banner is always big like the browser window
</div>

<div class="content">
   Content of the website
</div>
```

This is one way to do it:

```
.banner {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
background-color: red;
}

.content {
width: 100%;
position: relative;
background-color: green;
}
```

Problem is, if I use absolute position for this DIV the content of my website start from the top of the page and is hidden by the banner.

Is there any way to implement this without using javascript?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is there a `bottom: 0px` on the `.banner`? You don't want it going all the way to the bottom do you? How high is the banner? If the banner is 50px high, you could just add `margin-top: 50px;` to your `.content`.

Comment: @user3360873 did my answer fullfill your requirements? If your issue is fixed, please tick accepted :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bdh6b/6/)**

CSS:

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.banner {
    height:100%;
    background-color: red;
}
.content {
    background-color: green;
}
```

**Explanation :**

The point is to get a base that fits the total window size. You can get this base by setting `<body>` and `<html>` tags to 100% height (they expand the total width by default). They then expand to 100% height of the parent which is the window.

So you don't need absolute position anymore to size you elements like the winow.

You can use 100% height on the first level children (in your case `.banner`) to have them fit the total window height. You will not have to set 100% width on most elements as they automaticaly expand the whole width (block elements like `div`s that are not floated and in relative or static position).

Your page will keep the default positioning and your `.content` div will start just under the window size `.banner`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style>
.banner {

background-color: red;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

.content {
width: 100%;
margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-color: green;
height: 100%;

}
</style>
```